# Dropdown menu duplicates options whenever I want to clear it

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function that updates the values from my objects.
Whenever I do this I want to clear the drop down menu and refill it with the now updated values, aswell as displaying the newly updated object.
This kind of works except that it duplicates the updated value into my dropdown menu instead of clearing and refilling it.

The array:

```
var GeefSchermInfo = () => {
  let schermInfo = [{
      "Scherm": "Lobby",
      "Berichten": [{
          "Titel": "Welkom in onze school",
          "Tekst": "Het is hier dolle kookpret",
          "Duur": 5,
          "Image": "",
          "Tabel": []
        },
        {
          "Titel": "Lokaalverdeling",
          "Tekst": "",
          "Duur": 5,
          "Image": "",
          "Tabel":
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Scherm": "Speelplaats",
      "Berichten": [{
          "Titel": "Welkom in onze school",
          "Tekst": "Het is hier dolle kookpret",
          "Duur": 5,
          "Image": "https://www.feestkleding.nl/media/catalog/product/fk/k/o/kok-hoed-a.jpg",
          "Lokalen": []
        },
        {
          "Titel": "Maaltijden",
          "Tekst": "",
          "Duur": 5,
          "Image": "",
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
  return schermInfo;
}
```

Variabeles I made for better understanding:

```
var info = GeefSchermInfo();
```

My functions:

This fills the first drop down menu with the names of each object in the arry

```
//Vullen Selectiebox voor schermen
function ToonScherm(){ 
    for(var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
        var opt = info[i].Scherm;
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
        //Doorgeven welk scherm er bedoeld wordt.
        if (document.getElementById("crud")){
           SchermNummerVullen(opt); 
        } 
    }
}
```

This fills the second drop down menu with the amount of objects in the array.

```
//Vullen selectiebox schermnummers
function SchermNummerVullen(selectedScherm){
   for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++){
        if(info[i].Scherm == selectedScherm){
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = i+1;
            el.value = i+1;
            slcSchermNummer.appendChild(el);
        }
   }
}
```

This displays the (updated) info onto the screen:

```
//Pretty print van het gevraagde scherm
function ToonInfo(){
    var schermnummer;
    schermnummer = (slcSchermNummer.value)-1;
    for (var i=0; i<info.length; i++){
        if (info[i].Scherm == select.value){
            SchermenInfo.innerHTML = '"Scherm": "'+info[i].Scherm+'",\n'; 
            SchermenInfo.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(info[i].Berichten[schermnummer], null, 4);
            TextboxenVullen(i,schermnummer);
        }
    }
}
```

For better understanding I will add two screenshots:

This is how it looks when its loaded, everything works as intended

[image]

This is when I update one of the values, it starts duplicating in the dropdown menu

[image]

```
var GeefSchermInfo = () => {
    let schermInfo =
        [
            {
                "Scherm": "Lobby",
                "Berichten":
                    [
                        {
                            "Titel": "Welkom in onze school",
                            "Tekst": "Het is hier dolle kookpret",
                            "Duur": 5,
                            "Image": "",
                            "Tabel": []
                        },
                        {
                            "Titel": "Lokaalverdeling",
                            "Tekst": "",
                            "Duur": 5,
                            "Image": "",
                            "Tabel":
                                [
                                    { "Titelrij": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"] },
                                    { "1AA": ["SP 0.22", "SP 0.22", "SP 0.22", "SP 0.22", "", "LO", "Praktijk", "Praktijk"] },
                                    { "1AB": ["SP 0.23", "SP 0.23", "SP 0.23", "SP 0.23", "", "LO", "Praktijk", "Praktijk"] },
                                    { "2AA": ["LO", "SP 1.22", "SP 1.22", "SP 1.22", "", "SP0.24", "WET", "MAVO"] }
                                ]

                        }
                    ]
            },
            {
                "Scherm": "Speelplaats",
                "Berichten":
                    [
                        {
                            "Titel": "Welkom in onze school",
                            "Tekst": "Het is hier dolle kookpret",
                            "Duur": 5,
                            "Image": "https://www.feestkleding.nl/media/catalog/product/fk/k/o/kok-hoed-a.jpg",
                            "Lokalen": []
                        },
                        {
                            "Titel": "Maaltijden",
                            "Tekst": "",
                            "Duur": 5,
                            "Image": "",
                            "Tabel":
                                [
                                    { "Titelrij": ["Bistro", "Verzorgde dienst"] },
                                    { "1": ["2AB", "1AA 1-8"] },
                                    { "2": ["1AA 9-13", "2AA"] },
                                    { "3": ["1AT 1 -7", "1AB"] }
                                ]
                        }
                    ]
            }
        ]
    return schermInfo;
}

var info = GeefSchermInfo();

function ToonScherm(){ 
    for(var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
        var opt = info[i].Scherm;
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
        //Doorgeven welk scherm er bedoeld wordt.
        if (document.getElementById("crud")){
           SchermNummerVullen(opt); 
        } 
    }
}

function SchermNummerVullen(selectedScherm){
   for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++){
        if(info[i].Scherm == selectedScherm){
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = i+1;
            el.value = i+1;
            slcSchermNummer.appendChild(el);
        }
   }
}

function ToonInfo(){
    var schermnummer;
    schermnummer = (slcSchermNummer.value)-1;
    for (var i=0; i<info.length; i++){
        if (info[i].Scherm == select.value){
            SchermenInfo.innerHTML = '"Scherm": "'+info[i].Scherm+'",\n'; 
            SchermenInfo.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(info[i].Berichten[schermnummer], null, 4);
            TextboxenVullen(i,schermnummer);
        }
    }
}

function HervullenSelectieBoxen(){
    for (var i = 0; i <= select.options.length; i++)
    {
        select.remove(i-1);
    }
    for (var i=0; i <= slcSchermNummer.options.length; i++)
    {
        slcSchermNummer.remove(i-1);
    }
    ToonScherm();
    SchermNummerVullen();
    ToonInfo();
}
```

```css
button {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 80%;
}
/* Eigen Invulling */

#divFeedBack {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.container {
  grid-template-columns: 350px auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container{
  grid-template-columns: 400px auto;
  display:grid;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  display: grid;
  padding: 10px;
}
input {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

select {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width:100px;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
  <script src="../js/data.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
  <title>Schermen</title>
</head>

<body id="crud">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <!-- Rechterkant -->
        <div class="item">
          <h1>Digital signage</h1>
          <button id="btnHome"            onclick="location.href='../index.html'">Aanpassing bekijken</button>
          <div id="divOpties">
            <h2>Opties</h2>
            <label for="slcScherm">Scherm:</label><br />
            <select id="slcScherm"></select>
            <select id="slcSchermNummer"></select>
            <br/><br/>
            <label for="txtScherm">Scherm:</label>
            <input id="txtScherm" type="text" /><br />
            <label for="txtTitel">Titel:</label>
            <input id="txtTitel" type="text" /><br />
            <label for="txtTekst">Tekst:</label>
            <input id="txtTekst" type="text" /><br />
            <label for="txtDuur">Duur:</label>
            <input id="txtDuur" type="number" /><br />
            <label for="txtImage">Imagepad: </label>
            <input id="txtImage" type="text" /><br />
            <button id="btnBevestig">Bevestig aanpassingen</button>
          </div>
        </div>     
      <!-- Linkerkant -->
        <div class="item" id="divFeedBack">
            <pre id="SchermenInfo" > 
            </pre>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
var GeefSchermInfo = () => {
 let schermInfo =
  [
   {
    "Scherm": "Lobby",
    "Berichten":
     [
      {
       "Titel": "Welkom in onze school",
       "Tekst": "Het is hier dolle kookpret",
       "Duur": 5,
       "Image": "",
       "Tabel": []
      },
      {
       "Titel": "Lokaalverdeling",
       "Tekst": "",
       "Duur": 5,
       "Image": "",
       "Tabel":
        [
         { "Titelrij": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"] },
         { "1AA": ["SP 0.22", "SP 0.22", "SP 0.22", "SP 0.22", "", "LO", "Praktijk", "Praktijk"] },
         { "1AB": ["SP 0.23", "SP 0.23", "SP 0.23", "SP 0.23", "", "LO", "Praktijk", "Praktijk"] },
         { "2AA": ["LO", "SP 1.22", "SP 1.22", "SP 1.22", "", "SP0.24", "WET", "MAVO"] }
        ]

      }
     ]
   },
   {
    "Scherm": "Speelplaats",
    "Berichten":
     [
      {
       "Titel": "Welkom in onze school",
       "Tekst": "Het is hier dolle kookpret",
       "Duur": 5,
       "Image": "https://www.feestkleding.nl/media/catalog/product/fk/k/o/kok-hoed-a.jpg",
       "Lokalen": []
      },
      {
       "Titel": "Maaltijden",
       "Tekst": "",
       "Duur": 5,
       "Image": "",
       "Tabel":
        [
         { "Titelrij": ["Bistro", "Verzorgde dienst"] },
         { "1": ["2AB", "1AA 1-8"] },
         { "2": ["1AA 9-13", "2AA"] },
         { "3": ["1AT 1 -7", "1AB"] }
        ]
      }
     ]
   }
  ]
 return schermInfo;
}

function KoppelElementen(){
    h1Scherm = document.getElementById("h1Scherm");
    h2Titel = document.getElementById("h2Titel");
    pTekst = document.getElementById("pTekst");
    BerichtFoto = document.getElementById("BerichtFoto");
    SchermenInfo = document.getElementById("SchermenInfo");
    select = document.getElementById("slcScherm");
    txtScherm = document.getElementById("txtScherm");
    txtTekst = document.getElementById("txtTekst");
    txtTitel = document.getElementById("txtTitel");
    txtDuur = document.getElementById("txtDuur");
    txtImage = document.getElementById("txtImage");
    slcSchermNummer = document.getElementById("slcSchermNummer");
}
const info = GeefSchermInfo();

function Initieer(){
    KoppelElementen();
    ToonScherm(); 
}

function InitieerCrud(){
    KoppelElementen();
    ToonInfo();
    document.getElementById("slcScherm").onchange = ToonInfo;
    document.getElementById("slcSchermNummer").onchange = ToonInfo;
    document.getElementById("btnBevestig").onclick = InfoAanpassen;
}

function ToonScherm(){ 
    for(var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
        var opt = info[i].Scherm;
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
        //Doorgeven welk scherm er bedoeld wordt.
        if (document.getElementById("crud")){
           SchermNummerVullen(opt); 
        } 
    }
}

//Vullen selectiebox schermnummers
function SchermNummerVullen(selectedScherm){
   for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++){
        if(info[i].Scherm == selectedScherm){
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = i+1;
            el.value = i+1;
            slcSchermNummer.appendChild(el);
        }
   }
}

//Pretty print van het gevraagde scherm
function ToonInfo(){
    var schermnummer;
    schermnummer = (slcSchermNummer.value)-1;
    for (var i=0; i<info.length; i++){
        if (info[i].Scherm == select.value){
            SchermenInfo.innerHTML = '"Scherm": "'+info[i].Scherm+'",\n'; 
            SchermenInfo.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(info[i].Berichten[schermnummer], null, 4);
            TextboxenVullen(i,schermnummer);
        }
    }
}

//Bewerken van de info
function InfoAanpassen(){
    var schermnummer = (slcSchermNummer.value)-1;
    for (var i = 0; i < info.length;i++ ){
        if (select.value == info[i].Scherm){
            info[i].Scherm = txtScherm.value;
            var JuistObject = info[i].Berichten[schermnummer];
            JuistObject.Titel = txtTitel.value;
            JuistObject.Tekst = txtTekst.value;
            JuistObject.Duur = txtDuur.value;
            JuistObject.Image = txtImage.value;
            
            /*
            ToonInfo();
            ToonScherm();
            SchermNummerVullen();
            */

            HervullenSelectieBoxen();
        }
    }
}


//Hervullen van de selectieboxen
function HervullenSelectieBoxen(){
    for (var i = 0; i <= select.options.length; i++)
    {
        select.remove(i-1);
    }
    for (var i=0; i <= slcSchermNummer.options.length; i++)
    {
        slcSchermNummer.remove(i-1);
    }
    ToonScherm();
    SchermNummerVullen();
    ToonInfo();
}
```

```css
/* Eigen Invulling */

#divFeedBack {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.container {
  grid-template-columns: 350px auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container{
  grid-template-columns: 400px auto;
  display:grid;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  display: grid;
  padding: 10px;
}
input {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

select {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width:100px;
}

button {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
  <script src="../js/data.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
  <title>Schermen</title>
</head>

<body onload="InitieerCrud()" id="crud">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <!-- Rechterkant -->
        <div class="item">
          <h1>Digital signage</h1>
          <button id="btnHome" 
          <div id="divOpties">
            <h2>Opties</h2>
            <label for="slcScherm">Scherm:</label><br />
            <select id="slcScherm"></select>
            <select id="slcSchermNummer"></select>
            <br/><br/>
            <label for="txtScherm">Scherm:</label>
            <input id="txtScherm" type="text" /><br />
            <label for="txtTitel">Titel:</label>
            <input id="txtTitel" type="text" /><br />
            <label for="txtTekst">Tekst:</label>
            <input id="txtTekst" type="text" /><br />
            <label for="txtDuur">Duur:</label>
            <input id="txtDuur" type="number" /><br />
            <label for="txtImage">Imagepad: </label>
            <input id="txtImage" type="text" /><br />
            <button id="btnBevestig">Bevestig aanpassingen</button>
          </div>
        </div>     
      <!-- Linkerkant -->
        <div class="item" id="divFeedBack">
            <pre id="SchermenInfo" > 
            </pre>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to include as much code as possible that's relevant to my problem

Comment: Please click edit then `[<>]` snippet editor and produce a [mcve]

Comment: Also there are no variables in the object so just define it a `const info =
        [
            {
                "Scherm": "Lobby",....`

Comment: I put a snippet in there but it won't recognize the object.

Comment: Wrong pane. You have 3, top left is HTML (you did not put any) Top right is for the CSS and bottom left for the JavaScript. Edit it again, scroll down and click "edit above snippet" and add relevant HTML

Comment: Yeah,@mplungjan I was editing it. Because he won't recognize the object it is normally in another js file. Therefor the snippet doesn't really show my problem / my functions.

Comment: Tsjonge, jonge......

Comment: Do you know what the problem is by looking at the screenshots? It duplicates my dropdown menu options

Comment: I have no idea what I need to do to recreate your issue. It seems you posted two snippets on top of each other and neither seem to do anything

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

I removed the code inside my function HervullenSelectieBoxen()

replaced it with

```
//Hervullen van de selectieboxen
function HervullenSelectieBoxen(){
    slcSchermNummer.options.length = 0;
    select.options.length  = 0;
    ToonScherm();
    SchermNummerVullen();
    ToonInfo();
}
```

Not sure what was wrong with the previous code though :/